# Download genarated file from private folder

Tags: files

Ich wrote my module, that generates and save my file under private://myprivatfolder/myfile.txt
Now, I don't know how to download or make direct-access-url for this file after generation.

```
$url = url($path);
drupal_goto($url);
```

is not right way, I would work only with public folder.